# Storing really huge ints in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, gmp, gmpy

Is it possible to efficiently store big ints in MySQL? Not big as in `bigint`, more like 1000th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) or so, and there are at least hundreds of them. More likely, thousands. The speed of storing and loading values is a priority.

The numbers are created using [gmpy2](http://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html), Python's GMP wrapper. So it'd be nice if the stored numbers were accessible in the same format, but if not, I can always write a converter.

Comment: There are various ways you can do it. One way is ,You can store  number as a text (so 1000 places long number = 1000 char size word) and then convert back to int when needed.

Comment: if bigint is too big for you, use mediumint or int, never try to use strings for storing numbers, it will be _much_ slower. If you exceed bigint consider moving to two bigint columns and adding logic to split big number into 2 bigints

Comment: @Alexey How *much* slower will it be?

Comment: @Strawberry int is 4 bytes, mediumint is 3 bytes, bigint is 8 bytes. Number in string consumes number of digits + 2 or 4 bytes for string size. So for 1000 digit number it's 1000 times slower ;)

Comment: @Alexey and don't forget the added cost of operations on strings-as-ints or conversion to int. Those are about an order of magnitude slower than GMP arbitrary precision ints. Not precisely an SQL problem, but still a part of total runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the `mpz` integer to a Python string (for v2) or bytes (for v3) and save it as a BLOB entity in mysql. Here are the relevant `gmpy2` commands using Python 2.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.mpz(1234)
mpz(1234)
>>> gmpy2.to_binary(mpz(1234))
'\x01\x01\xd2\x04'
>>> gmpy2.from_binary('\x01\x01\xd2\x04')
mpz(1234)
>>>
```

`gmpy2.to_binary` will convert an arbitrary `gmpy2` object to a binary string. `gmpy2.from_binary` will convert the binary string back to a `gmpy2` object. The object's type is encoded into the binary string so you don't need to track the object's type.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.